# Turtlebot3 swarm

Tags: ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! To preface, I have (4) Turtlebots 3s and am using Ubuntu 16.02. My question is more of a directional one than anything. Basically, I would like to be able to write a single script that I can control the robots from, that would act as a management script of sorts to call separate scripts that would each signify an action to be performed while the bots autonomously map. I have tried to find a "jumping off" point but with no luck. All I am looking for is a suggestion of a direction to head in, as I'm just not sure where to start. I was thinking of assigning the robots their own name variables based on their IP addresses and going from there, but I'm not sure if that's even feasible in the ROS environment. Like I said, any suggestion of a direction to head in is greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296468/turtlebot3-swarm/) by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2018-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi :)
ROS has [Graph Resource Name](http://wiki.ros.org/Names) to encapsulate resources such as Nodes, Topics.
By using this, users can run multiple Nodes and make multiple Topics for robots.
Similar questions you asked are opened in [TurtleBot3 Issue page](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/issues/207). You can find some information about how to setup multiple turtlebot3.
Furthermore, we are preparing it to make more simple way to run. You can update new firmware and software near future.
Thanks

---

Originally posted by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) with karma: 811 on 2018-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1